data only written to named pipe after program quits
I am trying to write a program in Rust that writes a string to a named pipe. However, the data only shows up on the receiving end after the program quits.
Here's my code:
use termion::event::Key;
use termion::input::TermRead;
use termion::raw::IntoRawMode;
use std::io::Write;
use std::fs::{File, OpenOptions};

fn send_data(file: &mut File, payload: &str) -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
    file.write(payload.as_bytes()).unwrap();
    // I tried file.write_all() and file.flush(); same result
    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    let mut file = OpenOptions::new()
        .write(true)
        .open("/tmp/my_named_pipe")
        .expect("Failed to open named pipe for writing");

    let mut stdout = std::io::stdout().into_raw_mode().unwrap();
    stdout.flush().unwrap();

    loop {
        let key = match std::io::stdin().keys().next() {
            Some(Ok(input)) => input,
            _ => break,
        };
        match key { // press x to send data, q to quit
            Key::Char('q') => break,
            Key::Char('x') => send_data(&mut file, "foobar").unwrap(),
            _ => (),
        }
    }
}

I'm creating a named pipe with mkfifo /tmp/my_named_pipe and start listening to it with tail -f /tmp/my_named_pipe. Then, in a different terminal window, I run my program (and press 'x' several times). The 'tail -f' doesn't show anything. When I quit my program (by pressing 'q') all strings show all at once.
I'd expect every key press to call send_data() and every call to render on the tail -f side immediately. How can this be accomplished?

My implementation of tail -f does not print incomplete lines.  You can see the same behavior if you replace your program with { printf x; sleep 1; echo; }  You need something that reads the fifo without waiting for complete lines.

@WilliamPursell adding newlines to my payload doesn't change anything though. And writing echo "foobar" > /tmp/my_named_pipe in a different terminal does exactly what I want my rust program to do.

You need flush. tail needs \n (see earlier comment). So include in program. Then test, then post new tested program in question.

The problem comes from tail -f not properly watching the pipe. cat /tmp/my_named_pipe works perfectly even without \n.

@prog-fh That's it! Post your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as correct (still curious why tail -f is misbehaving...)

@Kolja I developed in an answer, as you suggested. Thanks.

As suggested, here is my comment slightly developed in an answer.
The problem does not stand on the Rust side, but on the tail -f side.
After creating the pipe with mkfifo /tmp/my_named_pipe, we can start a producer with:
( while true; do echo -n X ; sleep 1 ; done ) >/tmp/my_named_pipe

This writes a single X, without new-line, into the pipe, every second.
In another terminal, trying to consume the pipe with tail -f /tmp/my_named_pipe does not show anything till the producer is stopped.
This is the problem reported in the question.
If we replace echo -n X with echo X (i.e. we generate a new-line each time), in the producer, this does not change anything in the consumer.
Then, the problem is not related to tail waiting for a line before outputting anything; it's probably due to the way it watches a pipe (I did not take the time to study the source code).
However, trying to consume the pipe with dd if=/tmp/my_named_pipe bs=1 or simply cat /tmp/my_named_pipe shows an X every second, even without new-line.
This confirms that the problem is due to tail.
